# How to write BST search function in Standard ML?

Tags: sml

What is required is to write a function searchBST of type `''a tree -> (''a * ''a -> bool) -> ''a -> bool`
that searches a nst for a given data element. using:

```
datatype 'data tree = Empty 
                    | Node of 'data tree * 'data * 'data tree
```

Also, we cannot search every node in the tree, but only those nodes that, according to the definition, might contain the element we are looking for.

The function that I wrote is of type `(int * int tree -> bool)` and I would appreciate any tips on converting it to the required type

```
datatype 'data tree = Empty 
                    | Node of 'data tree * 'data * 'data tree;

fun searchBST (x, Empty) = false
  | searchBST (x, Node(l, parent, r)) =
      if x = parent then true 
      else 
       if x< parent then searchBST(x, l)
       else searchBST(x,r)
```

Comment: Presumably, this is homework. You should use the homework tag.

Answer (score 2):

When something has type `''a * ''a -> bool`, then it is always (99,9% of the times) a predicate function. This is strongly hinted by the fact that the argument tuple `''a * ''a` is an equality type (hence the douple mark, and not a single mark as "normal").

Since you are constructing a search function, your predicate function are most likely the one that should be used to define which element you are searching for. 
However it could also have been the case that it defines if the desired element is in the left or right part of the tree. Though normally it would then have been a ordering function with the type `''a * ''a -> order`. Such an ordering function would in any practical cases have been better, because you would then be able to abstract the ordering of element (which include equality) instead of hard coding a less than, which would then force your function to only work on integers (unless you type annotate to some other number type such as reals) instead of `''a` (equality) values.

Thus what you wan't (to get the desired type), is something of the form:

```
fun searchBST t p x =
```

where `t` is the tree, `p` is your predicate function and `x` is the value you wan't to find. Basically what you are missing is to use the predicate function in the test, instead of doing it directly.

```
fun searchBST Empty _ _ = false
  | searchBST (Node(l, d, r)) p x = 
     case (p(x, d), x < d) of
        (true, _) => true
      | (_, true) => searchBST l p x
      | (_, false) => searchBST r p x
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing this part in your code " (''a * ''a -> bool) " take it into consideration,  work on the tuples then your code would work. the two ''a 's  are the element your searching for and the element from the node.